# Array of Strings without declaring a new array

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop

I believe in other languages, you can do the following:

```
for (String foo : new String[]{"string1", "string2", "string3"}) {
    //do something with foo
}
```

However with Java, I get an error with

```
new String[]{"string1", "string2", "string3"}
```

Is something like this possible in Java, or do I have to create the new array like so:

```
final String[] bar = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
for (String foo : bar) {
    //do something with foo
}
```

Comment: What error do you get, and in what context?

Comment: Works fine for me in JavaSE 8. Maybe the problem is with whatever you are doing to `foo`.

Comment: @PEF Whoops, I had mine set to JDK7. It works now that I have it set to JDK8. Thanks!